# XSS with dynamic HTML input

Tags: html, jsp, xss, owasp

My team is fixing vulnerability threats from an old jsp application. The problem is it allows (permissioned) users to create a simple home page by putting their html into a textarea and having it render on the page. The problem is xss issues. I have been doing some research and found withing the jsp pages I can use:

fn:escapeXML() from the jstl library to escape any html/xml that is inputted. This is fine for simple form inputs, but for the home page creator, I want to be able to keep simple html but get rid of any harmful scripts or xss vulnerabilities.

My teammate and I are fairly new to fixing xss issues and have been relying on resources we find..

I have come across these resources and am not sure if this will work the way I like after reading through them.

-[Which html sanitization library to use?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20354866/which-html-sanitization-library-to-use)

-https://www.owasp.org/index.php/XSS_%28Cross_Site_Scripting%29_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet

If I use owasp, will this sanitize the html to basic rendering and prevent any scripting from being implemented?

Here is what I currently have in my jsp:

```
<td class='caption'>
  <c:set var="x"><%=system.getName()%></c:set>
  Options for ${fn:escapeXml(x)}
</td>
```

This works and will currently stop any html/xml/script from running but I still would like basic html (titles, paragraphs, fonts, colors, etc) for a simple informational page with html.

Answer (score 0):

According to [OWASP](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/XSS_%28Cross_Site_Scripting%29_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet#RULE_.236_-_Sanitize_HTML_Markup_with_a_Library_Designed_for_the_Job)

> If your application handles markup -- untrusted input that is supposed to contain HTML -- it can be very difficult to validate. Encoding is also difficult, since it would break all the tags that are supposed to be in the input. Therefore, you need a library that can parse and clean HTML formatted text.

There is different [HTML sanitizing libraries](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1947021/libs-for-html-sanitizing). The [owasp-java-html-sanitizer library](https://code.google.com/p/owasp-java-html-sanitizer/) is probably a good choice.

You can use [prepackaged policies](http://owasp-java-html-sanitizer.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/distrib/javadoc/org/owasp/html/Sanitizers.html):

```
PolicyFactory policy = Sanitizers.FORMATTING.and(Sanitizers.LINKS);
String safeHTML = policy.sanitize(untrustedHTML);
```

configure your [own policy](http://owasp-java-html-sanitizer.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/distrib/javadoc/org/owasp/html/HtmlPolicyBuilder.html):

```
PolicyFactory policy = new HtmlPolicyBuilder()
   .allowElements("a")
   .allowUrlProtocols("https")
   .allowAttributes("href").onElements("a")
   .requireRelNofollowOnLinks()
   .build();
String safeHTML = policy.sanitize(untrustedHTML);
```

or write [custom policies](http://owasp-java-html-sanitizer.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/distrib/javadoc/org/owasp/html/ElementPolicy.html):

```
PolicyFactory policy = new HtmlPolicyBuilder()
    .allowElements("p")
    .allowElements(
        new ElementPolicy() {
          public String apply(String elementName, List<String> attrs) {
            attrs.add("class");
            attrs.add("header-" + elementName);
            return "div";
          }
        }, "h1", "h2", "h3", "h4", "h5", "h6"))
    .build();
String safeHTML = policy.sanitize(untrustedHTML);
```

Read the [documentation](http://owasp-java-html-sanitizer.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/distrib/javadoc/index.html) for full details.